# Toggle visibility of text box based on status of check box--jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, visibility

So I have a list of races for a survery form.  there is a box named 'other specify' for those people that don't meet any of the other criteria. I need a text book to become visible when 'other specify' is checked, and to dissappear when it's not.  I have been able to make the box appear when another is checked, but not dissappear when it was unchecked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

---

Jscript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
 <script language="JavaScript">

 $(function(){ 
  $('#other').click(function(){ 
  $('#otherrace').toggle(
          function(event) {
            $(event.target).css('visible');
          },
          function(event) {
            $(event.target).css('hidden');
          }
        );
      });


    </script>
```

---

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="race"  id="other"value="other" />Other, specify<br />
<div style="visibility:hidden" id="race"><input type="text" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="25" id="otherrace" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/K3kvE/

```
$('#other').change(function(){ 
    $('#otherrace').parent().css( 'visibility', this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden' );
});
```

or use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` and do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/K3kvE/1/

```
$('#other').change(function(){ 
    $('#otherrace').parent().toggle( this.checked );
});
```

The way you were using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was as a "toggle event", which means you were effectively assigning a click event that toggles between executing the functions you pass it.

Because it is the parent of `otherrace` that is being hidden, you need to traverse up to it using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), then set its `visibility` property to `hidden` or `visible` depending on the state of the checkbox.

The second solution changes from using `visibility` property to using `display` so that [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be called in a different manner. The way it is being called now, it toggles between [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), which set the `display` property from `none` to its original setting and back.

Comment: @user113716 jsFiddle links are down